# extension method on enum not being called

Tags: c#, enums

I've done a fair bit of reading and there are plenty of answers to very similar questions but even following those I can't get this to work. The extension method is static, public, has `this`,  is in the same namespace so should not need importing... what am I missing? My C# isn't great.

```
namespace LDB
{

    public enum Neg { isNegated, notNegated };

    static class NegStringifier {
        public static string ToString(this Neg n) {
            string res = n switch {
                Neg.isNegated => "flowers",
                Neg.notNegated => "kittens",
                //_ => null
            };
            return res;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(Neg.isNegated.ToString());
            System.Console.WriteLine(Neg.notNegated.ToString());
            ...
```

output:

```
isNegated
notNegated
```

Apologies up front, I know this is going to be something trivial but I can't see what.

Comment: I think so! Could you close the question please, and if you wish to delete it I'd be ok with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler only looks for extension methods when it can't find any "regular" instance methods that are applicable for the method call. In this case, the `object` class provides a `ToString()` method, so there *is* an appropriate method there, and that's what the compiler uses.

If you change `ToString` to some other name (e.g. `ExtensionToString`) in both the extension method and calling code, you'll see it being used.

Comment: So my method is being hidden. Would it not be a thing for the compiler to report this as unreachable?

Comment: @user3779002: No, it's not being hidden - it's not being looked for. And it's not unreachable - you could call `NegStringifier.ToString(Neg.isNegated)` for example.